# Plywood and underlayment question for large format tile

Tags: bathroom, tile, plywood

I have taken my bathroom floor down to the joists. I plan on installing a curbless shower witch requires a 1 1/8" recess. Can I use 1" plywood with Ditra to get to my 1 1/8 height and lay large format tile on top of that. Is 2 pieces of 1/2 better?

Comment: I'm a little confused. The curbless shower itself still needs subfloor sheathing, right? Are you stacking this 1-1/8" layer on top of a uniform layer of subfloor sheathing?

Comment: It is not clear at all, what you mean.  Why would you tile under the shower cubicle?  How deep is teh floor that you are removing?